# Elementary Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$Ax=b$ with $A$ integer Matrix and $b$ integer vector.

Looking for solutions $x_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

So if we multiply by elementary transformation matrices:
(Add an integer multiply of one column/row to another row/column, Exchange two columns/rows, multiply one column/row by +-1)

$UAx=Ub$ then the solution space stays the same? Is this correct?

Also for column operation:

$AUx = bU$

is this right?

Answer (score 0):

$$UAx=Ub\Rightarrow U(Ax-b)=0$$
If $AB=0\Rightarrow A=0 \vee B=0$? **Not always**

Just in the case of elementary transformations, multiply them by $A$ doesn't change the solution space. What do you need to be this true for any matrix $B$? The transformation related to $B$ must be injective, thus $B(Ax)=Bb\Rightarrow Ax=b$

Comment: Ok so elementary transformation change the integer solution space? i tought it stays the same?!?!

Comment: No, if you use elementary transformation it doesn't change Kernel of Space, but it dont works in general with a matrix $M$

Comment: Yeah but thats what i wanted to know if U is of the elementary type i described it doesn't change the solution space?

Comment: No, it doesn't change the solution space, you can use this fact for write $A=LU$, where $L,U$ are triangular matrix (Lowe and Upper) , and for solve $Ax=b$ you have to do $L(Ux)=b$, then if $y$ is a solution you have to do $Ux=y$

Comment: and for elementary matrices U is UA = AU^T or UA=AU^{-1} is there connection between those?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think $U^\intercal=U^{-1}$

Comment: no this not right. But U*A*x = U*b seems natural, while AUx = bU not because you don't right multiply the same equation?

Comment: when you do $A\times B$, you must see the order of each matrix, it must be like $A_{n\times m}\times B_{m\times n}$, that's why you can do the right multiply.

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez:  Perhaps you could find time to incorporate some of the clarifications you've made in Comments into your Answer.  While I'm sure the connection of the two lines you've written there to the Question are clear to you, the necessity of the additional comments is a good indication that the Answer can be improved.

Comment: @hardmath, okey, i'll try to improve my answer, thanks!